IONOS shared hosting not allowing laravel api calls instead returning internal 500 error
I have two issues that seem loosely related. Firstly if I refresh the page or go back or forward to any page which isn't the root page it causes a 500 error and if I attempt to make API calls I am similarly met with 500 errors.
So I am hosting my application on IONOS it is a laravel project with the front-end developed using react. I have also setup a database with IONOS and migrated the database schema using artisan. It loads all the pages just fine.
My first issue is if I refresh the page on any page which isn't the root or go forward or backward it causes an internal server error 500 and secondly if I try to make API calls I similarly get a return of a 500 error. I don't have access to server logs as it is shared hosting and what customer support I have received hasn't really helped resolved much of anything.
I believe the issue related to the host as locally I can get everything working just fine. I have attempted to change the .htaccess within the laravel project to what I have seen elsewhere:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteBase /

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
</IfModule>

However, this hasn't done much and I still have both problems described. I have even changed most of the permissions to 775/777 however to no avail.
Here is the web site in question: it is the reservation booking page I am having issues with as this should allow for interaction with the database and making bookings: text

Laravel usually creates its own error log files, as long as it has permission to write to the directory. They can be found in the project's directory under storage/logs. Otherwise, you'll definitely try to get an answer from support. A 500 error is extremely generic, so you can't troubleshoot from just that error.

So the storage/logs don't seem to be storing any information I am unsure why. I even gave the directory 777 permission but still nothing
